# Deep learning model stops learning after 30 iterations

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to implement a deep learning model that I made while completing the "Neural Networks and Deep Learning" course on Coursera, using the MNIST dataset for written numbers. During the course, it worked very well identifying cats so I know that the whole model works together, and I have modified all of the input data and the output layer such that the output is an array of size 10 and the array shapes all match what they were during the course.

I have done a little experimentation and come to a very weird problem. My graph of cost over time looks like this:
[image: mnist training cost over time]

I would usually expect a more sloping curve that would tend towards a value much closer to zero and the very sharp turn is odd as well. I should also point out that it isn't hundreds, it's tens on the x axis.

The shape of my NN is [784, 200, 50, 10], I'm assuming that this isn't the problem but what I'm really looking for is for someone more experienced in ml to explain why this happens.

My model as it stands goes something like this

```
# Initialisation of parameters
parameters = initialize_parameters_deep(layers_dims)

for i in range(0, num_iterations):

    # Forward propagation: [LINEAR -> RELU]*(L-1) -> LINEAR -> SIGMOID.
    AL, caches = L_model_forward(train_data, parameters, layers_dims[-1])

    # Compute cost.
    cost = compute_cost(AL, train_labels)

    # Backward propagation.
    grads = L_model_backward(AL, train_labels, caches)

    # Update parameters.
    parameters = update_parameters(parameters, grads, learning_rate)


    # Print the cost every 100 training example
    if print_cost and i % 100 == 0:
        print("Cost after iteration %i: %f" % (i, cost))
    if print_cost and i % 10 == 0:
        costs.append(cost)
```

My backward propagation model is as follows

```
def linear_backward(dZ, cache):
    A_prev, W, b = cache
    m = A_prev.shape[1]

    dW = 1 / m * np.dot(dZ, A_prev.T)
    db = 1 / m * np.sum(dZ, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    dA_prev = np.dot(W.T, dZ)

    assert (dA_prev.shape == A_prev.shape)
    assert (dW.shape == W.shape)
    assert (db.shape == b.shape)

    return dA_prev, dW, db


def linear_activation_backward(dA, cache, activation):

    linear_cache, activation_cache = cache

    if activation == "relu":
        dZ = relu_backward(dA, activation_cache)
        dA_prev, dW, db = linear_backward(dZ, linear_cache)

    elif activation == "sigmoid":
        dZ = sigmoid_backward(dA, activation_cache)
        dA_prev, dW, db = linear_backward(dZ, linear_cache)

    return dA_prev, dW, db


def L_model_backward(AL, Y, caches):
    grads = {}
    L = len(caches)  # the number of layers
    m = AL.shape[1]
    Y = Y.reshape(AL.shape)  # after this line, Y is the same shape as AL

    # Initializing the backpropagation
    dAL = - (np.divide(Y, AL) - np.divide(1 - Y, 1 - AL))

    # Lth layer (SIGMOID -> LINEAR) gradients. Inputs: "dAL, current_cache". Outputs: "grads["dAL-1"], grads["dWL"], grads["dbL"]
    current_cache = caches[L - 1]
    grads["dA" + str(L - 1)], grads["dW" + str(L)], grads["db" + str(L)] = linear_activation_backward(dAL, current_cache, activation="sigmoid")

    # Loop from l=L-2 to l=0
    for l in reversed(range(L - 1)):
        # lth layer: (RELU -> LINEAR) gradients.
        # Inputs: "grads["dA" + str(l + 1)], current_cache". Outputs: "grads["dA" + str(l)] , grads["dW" + str(l + 1)] , grads["db" + str(l + 1)]
        current_cache = caches[l]
        dA_prev_temp, dW_temp, db_temp = linear_activation_backward(grads["dA" + str(l + 1)], current_cache, activation="relu")
        grads["dA" + str(l)] = dA_prev_temp
        grads["dW" + str(l + 1)] = dW_temp
        grads["db" + str(l + 1)] = db_temp

    return grads
```

If you need any more code or anything from me specifically then I would be happy to provide it.

Comment: What is your `learning rate` and `optimization function`?

Comment: I don't think that graph is indicating something odd, or something gone wrong. How is your model performance? I would guess by this graph it's doing well. Cost has no obligation to fall to 0, it can take an arbitrarily high value, just so long as it's minimised. As for the sharp turn, it just means that each gradient descent step is equally as effective at reducing cost, until it's minimised. You're using the full training data each iteration (batch gradient descent), so it's not surprising.

Comment: So the Learning rate is set at 0.1 currently, the optimisation function is just basic backwards differentiation and an update of parameters. ive just checked the effectiveness of my model by running the entire training set and the testing set through the L_model_forward function and I got a little below 10% accuracy each. so I really don't know what to do

Comment: come to think of it if it's below 10% then it is actually worse than just randomly picking, so I think its an issue with having 10 outputs rather than one output that I had on the course.

Comment: Could you provide the entire code, or a link to where I can get it? I'd be happy to take a look and see what the issue may be.

Comment: I dont know if this will work but here is a github repo "https://github.com/Ollie-spoon/Deep_Learning_MNIST_First" it doesn't contain the training set because its too big to upload to github. I hope this helps